# How to get data from GitHub API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, github-api

I'm writing a functional ReactJS app that search for GitHub users and displays them in a list. The user list should display the number of user repositories. But the problem is that I don't know how to get a list of repositories for each user, but I only know how to search for the repositories of one specific user.

On the main page, I search for users whose names match the input value and get a list of matches. If I go to the page of this user, then in it I can already get a list and the number of repositories of this user, but for this I have to send a separate request to the server for the user.

Is there any solution that will allow me to display the number of repositories for each user on the main page?

[CodeSanbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-cdn-0kpwv?file=/src/components/Home.js)

Inside Sanbox my code is unstable, but i hope, the main point must be clear

Finally it should looks like this, but instead ## symbols should be count of repos each users

[image: Finnaly it should looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

You can count the repositories of a particular getting the data from here: https://api.github.com/users/**username**/repos

And count the number of items in the response using :

```
Object.keys(resultData).length;
```

Here resultData is the response of the GET from the API above

Answer (score 0):

You can use the axios library, import it, and add useEffect or useState to your program.

One API you can use is https://api.github.com/users/someUserName/repos

Their documentation should be helpful. You can then map through the elements returned in the array with a key. You can also count the number of items and get their corresponding index.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I still don't understand how to implement this in practice, could you show me how to implement this solution into my code?

Comment: Here's a good documentation of it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-axios-react